# Edit and deleteRow functions in code not called when button clicked

Tags: angularjs

I am population angular-datatable using server side response . Issue is i am not able to call the function in html added through renderWith(actionsHtml). 
var vm = this;

```
vm.edit = edit;

vm.deleteRow = deleteRow;


var draw = 0;
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
        .withOption('serverSide', true)
        .withOption('ajax', function(data, callback, settings) {
  // make an ajax request using data.start and data.length

  $http.post('/getProduct/api/call', {
    draw: draw,
    store_id: Session.sessionuserid(),
    limit: data.length,
    offset: data.start,
    contains: data.search.value
  }).success(function(res) {
    // map your server's response to the DataTables format and pass it to
    // DataTables' callback
    draw = res.draw;

    callback({
      recordsTotal: res.meta,
      recordsFiltered: res.meta,
      draw: res.draw,
      data: res.data
    });
  });
}).withDataProp('data');

vm.dtColumns = [
  DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name').withTitle('PRODUCT NAME'),
  DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('price').withTitle('PRICE'),
  DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('offer_flag').withTitle('Weekly Special'),
  DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Actions').notSortable()
          .renderWith(actionsHtml)
];


function actionsHtml(data, type, full, meta) {

  return '<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="showCase.edit(' + data.id + ')">' +
          '   <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>' +
          '</button>&nbsp;' +
          '<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="showCase.deleteRow(' + data.id + ')">' +
          '   <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>' +
          '</button>';
}
```

These functions are not called when buttons pressed
     function edit(id) {
      console.log(id);
      TempStore.addID(id);
      $location.path('/editproduct');
    }

```
function deleteRow(id) {

  var msgbox = $dialog.messageBox('Delete Product', 'Are you sure?', [{label: 'Yes, I\'m sure', result: 'yes'}, {label: 'Nope', result: 'no'}]);
  msgbox.open().then(function(result) {
    if (result === 'yes') {

      $scope.removeproduct = Restdata.remove({sailsModel: 'products', id: id}, function() {
        $window.location.reload();
      });
    }
  });
}
;
```

Here is my HTML :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your DataTable is rendered, you need to recompile with `$compile` in order to bind your `$scope` and angular directives to the produces HTML:

```
vm.dtOptions = DTOptions.newOptions()
    .withOption('createdRow', createdRow)
    ... // other options

function createdRow(row, data, dataIndex) {
    // Recompiling so we can bind Angular directive to the DT
    $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
}
```

See the [documentation](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/bindAngularDirective) on how to bind angular directives.